# How to update the record range in a vuetify data table manually?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have a v-data-table like in this example https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#paginate-and-sort-server-side
server-side pagination and sorting. I have a couple of dropdowns that work as filters for the same API which populates the same data table.
My issue is when I change the filter the record range gets a wrong value. Is there a way to reset all the footer components. I checked the docs I couldn't find a way.

[image]

Comment: Can you show some of your code

Comment: You can set a `:key="X"` for `data-table` and make it rerender by changing the `X`

Comment: For example: `<v-data-table :key="JSON.stringify(options)" :options.sync="options" ... />`

Comment: Hi @talkhabi it did change the record range to correct one, but now when I click on arrows it doesn't trigger the API call. any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should use another key instead of `:key="JSON.stringify(options)"`, it is related to your project and states.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the component re-render with a [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) attribute.

So declare your component like:

```
<template>
  <data-table :key="componentKey" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      componentKey: 0 
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

Then increase your `componentKey` to force the re-render.