# Vue computed property updated, but component did not re-render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am filling a vuetify data-table with data loaded asynchronously into a vuex store.
User input can change the store, in which case I `dispatch` an action, that pulls some data asynchronously and `commits` changes.

To handle the component state when data is loading, I use a `loading` flag in the store. When the data is being loaded, it is set to `loading` so that the data table renders as empty

```
...
computed: {
  ... // a fairly long list of interdependent computed properties
  loading() {
    return store.state.loading
  },
  dataToDisplay() {
     if(this.loading){
        return []
     } else{
        return store.state.data
     }
  }
}
```

This works well, but sometimes the data-table component does not update, even though the computed property that feeds it is updated (See screenshot of vue dev tools).

[image]

There are several answers about why computed properties do not update ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678983/vue-js-computed-property-not-updating), [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/component-not-re-rendering-when-state-changes/24156)). But what can explain that **the computed property did update correctly, but the component did not re-render?** How to fix it?

Someone mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280919/how-to-update-the-record-range-in-a-vuetify-data-table-manually) using a `:key` I tried that but the table content is still not updating.

**[edit] providing the data-table code**

```html
<v-data-table 
   :key="loading"
   :headers="headers"
   :items="dataToDisplay"
   :item-key="itemId"
   disable-pagination hide-default-footer
>
  <template v-slot:item="row">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.currentCondition }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-right">{{ row.item.nextCondition }}</td>
    <td class="mx-2">
      <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="editItem(row.item)">
        <v-icon color="teal">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="deleteItem(row.item)">
        <v-icon color="pink">mdi-delete</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: From this article, I could force re-render. That being said, I'd better know what is happening to come up with a better solution https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: Your component will be automatically re-render if your `key` updated. otherwise you need to force re-render.

Comment: OK, so what is the key of a data-table? Are you talking about item-key?
To give more context, I am passing a [{col1:value, col2:value}, {col1:value,col2:value}] to `<v-data-table :items="dataToDisplay" :item-key="idNumber">`

Comment: *This works well, **but sometimes the data-table component does not update**.* when do you have this behavior ? please share the store code

Comment: The store is quite complex, but essentially the flow is: a user deletes or filters out a table element. This submits a request to firebase, and concurrently removes the element from the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a data attribute `items: null` which gets filled by your function and load them into your `v-data-table` using `v-for: (item, i) in items`

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :loading="loading"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          { text: 'Name', align: 'start', value: 'name'},
          { text: 'Description', value: 'desc' },
        ],
        items: null,
        loading: true
      }
    },
    created: {
      addData() {
        this.items = store.state.data
        this.loading = store.state.loading
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! The user does modify the state from time to time though. It means that the state needs to be re-loaded after that. So I am guessing the created() hook will work for initialization, but not afterwards.

Comment: Vuetify made it so that the datatable updates when the items used in `v-for` change. you could use computed, but I would highly recommend also using a data attribute.

Comment: I am not using v-for however (Sorry about the vagueness of the question, I updated the template). In your solution, where would the logic for updating the items after a user action be? Would they be inside a method then, instead of being triggered through a computed field?